# Como pegar valores de um array sem array.push

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, array

Galera, to tentando pegar a localização de um usuário e ela ficar atualizando de tempos em tempos, pesquisando, achei esse método, porém, não consigo só fazer isso com o valor atual do array, ele concatena (push) e adiciona infinitamente.. alguém sabe como posso solucionar isso?

```
 var array = [];
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lon = position.coords.longitude;
   var vel = position.coords.speed;
   array.push(lat, lon, vel); 
   locationCode()  
});

function locationCode() {
   console.log(array)
   alert(array[0]);
}
```

Comment: E se vc colocasse `var array = [];` no início da função?

Comment: como assim? não entendi

Comment: Você pode criar um objeto e atualizar o mesmo em vez de um array, na minha opinião fica até mais claro

Comment: Essa linha `var array = [];` está fora da função `function(position) {`, certo? Se vc colocasse dentro, logo no início?

Comment: Assim toda vez que a função for chamada, a array será reiniciada do zero.

Comment: vou tentar, vou colocar ela logo no início, obrigado pela ideia, vou testar.

Comment: infelizmente não deu, array is not defined

Comment: Mantenha o array fora e dentro zere ele `var array = []; navigator.geo... { array = []`

Comment: Certo. Então deixa como estava, e dentro da função coloca só `array = [];`, sem o `var`

Comment: cara, vocês são gênios, funcionou!

Comment: Aí @GuilhermeCostamilam, posta a resposta aí.

Comment: galera, agora surgiu mais um problema como sempre na informatica, tem como eu obter o valor do array fora da função? preciso dele para marcar no mapa a localização em tempo real do usuário

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas uma explicação:

```
var array = []; //Cira o array
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
   array = []; //Zera o array

   //Cria variáveis com os valores
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lon = position.coords.longitude;
   var vel = position.coords.speed;

   //Adiciona os valores ao array
   array.push(lat, lon, vel);

   //Chama uma função que mostra os dados
   locationCode()  
});

function locationCode() {
   console.log(array)
   alert(array[0]);
}
```

Você pode fazer um pouco mais enxuto:

```
let array = [];

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
    array = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, position.coords.speed];

    alert(array);
    console.log(array);
});
```